# Any EventBroker/Aggregator for winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, events

hopefully there are some working samples
else any place where to start looking

Ideally should be able to able to execute methods on Background/Foreground method as marked/attributed

Comment: -1: You'll need to make your question much more detailed than that. I can't tell what you want.

Comment: EventBroker like in SCSF but without SCSF,EntLib etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/EventBroker.aspx) implementation of an event broker from CodeProject.

It is based on attributes and supports thread synchronization, weak references (so as not to interfere with garbage collection) and a simple hierarchy system.

I haven't used it myself but the author states that it is based on the event broker from [Composite (UI) Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx) which I have found quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the reputation to comment on Nathan's answer, but I thought this might save some legwork for anyone searching for the latest version of EventBroker.  It is now packaged as part of [Appccelerate](http://www.appccelerate.com/eventbroker.html) which is available via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Appccelerate.EventBroker/).  I've not used it yet, but I plan to evaluate it.